# sprite event "DataViz.MOUSE_CLICK" getting triggered only once

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, forge

first thing i did is rendered some sprite and then using Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core i have added an event listener onto viewer, of type DATAVIZ_OBJECT_CLICK, but when i am clicking on the sprite. the callback function passed when this event gets triggered is being called only once.I wonder why it can happend.

```
      const dataVizCore = Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core;
      function onSpriteClicked(event) {
        console.log(event, 'sprite clicked');
        const e = new Event('lol', { payload: 'payload' });
        dispatchEvent(e);
      }
      console.log('event registered');
      viewer.addEventListener(dataVizCore.MOUSE_CLICK, onSpriteClicked);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to https://hyperion.autodesk.io, and run the following command in the console:

```js
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(dataVizCore.MOUSE_CLICK, () => { console.log('Sprite clicked!'); });
```

You'll see that the callback function is actually called every time you click on a sprite. However, note that the callback is only triggered when you click and select a **different sprite**. I guess the method should be called `SPRITE_SELECTED` or something like that instead of `MOUSE_CLICK`. I will report this to the engineering team.

Comment: thanks for mentioning any workaround for now? like deselect the currently selected one automatic after selecting it. i just need to throw out an event

Comment: One option would be to grab a reference to the "HyperionTool" (`tool = viewer.toolController.getTool('HyperionTool')`), and whenever the `MOUSE_CLICK` triggers, set `tool.selectedDbId = 0`. That way the tool will never remember which sprite was clicked last, and the event will trigger _always_.